# с++ как получить время для функции rand в микро или нано секундах

Tags: c++

у меня есть функция :

[image: извините что скрин приложение ругалось на код]

но определять в секундах время то если использовать функцию чаще чем в 1 секунду то результат один и тот-же как мне сделать чтобы он опирался на время в микро или нано секундах
(желательно в нано) всё равно от куда они будут браться хоть при запуске приложения хоть мировые главное что в нано или микро секундах.

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Вы всерьез планируете вызывать `srand` в программе более одного раза?!!!

Comment: Так вы делайте инициализацию генератора **один раз** (при старте программы, например), а потом берите следующее случайное число rand много раз

Answer (score 3):

*Никогда*, **никогда**, ***НИКОГДА*** не используйте `srand()` перед каждым `rand()`.

Ибо `rand()` сам каждый раз инициализирует генератор очередным псевдослучайным значением, а вызывая `srand()`, вы инициализируете  генератор собственным (кстати, далеко не случайным) значением и тем самым мешаете его работе!

Вызвать `srand()` в программе достаточно один раз, и то только для того, чтоб разные запуски программ работали с разными последовательностями псевдослучайных значений...

Comment: @MBo попробую перефразировать...

Comment: а тогда как мне это писать можно пожалуйста код функции

Comment: Просто вытрите строку с `srand`...